# Bitcoin poisson density into code

Tags: c++, probability, bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoinj

The following is from the [Bitcoin whitepaper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf). The goal was to calculate the probability (P) an attacker could get lucky and override z number of blocks with q is the percentage of the network in control.

[image]

I'm interested in moving backwards from this and calculating the percentage of the network the attacker would have to control in order to roll back x blocks given some probability of success P.

Is this possible or am I thinking about this weird?

How would I represent solving for q instead of p in code?

```
    Converting to C code...
    #include <math.h>
    double AttackerSuccessProbability(double q, int z)
    {
       double p = 1.0 - q;
       double lambda = z * (q / p);
       double sum = 1.0;
       int i, k;
       for (k = 0; k <= z; k++) {
             double poisson = exp(-lambda);
             for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
                     poisson *= lambda / i;
                     sum -= poisson * (1 - pow(q / p, z - k));
             }
       return sum;
       }
    }
```